# Logout from Facebook programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

The problem is that Facebook use Safari when logged in, so when I try logout from my app it does keep credentials and cookies of Safari.
In other words, the only way to logout correctly is to open Safari and logout from Facebook.
My question is, is there any work around this way?

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [FBSDKLoginManager new];
[loginManager logOut];
```

I also tried:

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
```

Although they are being called inside the logout method :(

Finally I tried removing cookies

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

No luck at all!

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: Do you want to log out from your app or in Facebook safari ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible (programmatically) if you are using SFSafariViewController (via FB SDK, or yourself) to login into FB.

Comment: @AnthoninC. I want to logout from my app.

Comment: @msk It's Facebook lib which shows SFSafariViewController, I've no control there :(

Comment: You don't have facebook app installed?

Comment: No, would it matter?

Comment: Yes. I don't have any problem to logout with FB SDK so the issue probably comes from here. I will check in a few hours.